# How to access subcolumns of pandas dataframe and plot them in Python

Tags: python, pandas, boxplot

I have following pandas dataframe. How can I access subcolumns of this dataframe and plot them (eg. plotting distribution of min values using boxplot)

I am using following python statement but I am not getting the output.

df.boxplot(column=['score']['min'])

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a multi-level column you have to pass it as a tuple. To read more indexing multi-level structure go through pandas doc [`MultiIndex / advanced indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html).

```
df.boxplot(column=[('score', 'min')])
```

Or, use [`df.xs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html), in this case return type is `Series`, to boxplot `Series` use [`Series.plot.box`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.plot.box.html).

```
df.xs(('score', 'min')).plot.box()
```